# What does 'x' here mean?

Tags: c, data-structures

```
CHAINED-HASH-INSERT(T,x)
 Insert x at head of list T[h(x.key)]

CHAINED-HASH-SEARCH(T,k)
 Search for an element with key k in list T[h(k)]

CHAINED-HASH-DELETE(T,x)
 Delete x from the list T[h(x.key)]
```

I am studying hash tables right now and I am not able to understand what exactly **x** means in the attached pseudocode with this question. The three hash table dictionary functions are being implemented here to insert, search and delete an element from the table.
Now I understand what x.key means but the problem is, but what exactly is x  in the data that has to be inserted into the table. Please can you help me with an example. I am currently trying to implement it using C.
**Also h() is the hash function**.

Comment: x is an element of the list

Answer (score 1):

In practice it will be a `struct` for key/value pairs. `x.key` is the key that is used for the hashing. The value might be named `x.value`, or `x.data` or something like that. There must be a definition for the type of `x` somewhere, but it's name is not important to understand the algorithm and to implement it. You might use a void pointer to represent the value so that data of any kind could be stored in the hash table.

So `x` represents the data structure that is stored in the hash table's collision resolution list, which is where the key and value are stored.

**Update**

I have found this familiar looking reference which explains it all:  [Introduction to Algorithms](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ecsli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap12.htm)